# case statements for different date columns

Tags: oracle, if-statement, case, between

I'm facing issues while writing the below code in SQL developer:

```
 'If Trim$(psFromDate) <> "" and NOT ISNULL(psFromDate) AND Trim$(psToDate) <> "" and NOT ISNULL(psToDate) Then
select case ps_datetype
 CASE "CTA"
    wc = wc & " AND (trunc(sf_get_local (p_con.created_date,p_con.cdate_tz_code)) Between "
    wc = wc & " TO_DATE (" & "'" & sFromDate & "'" & ", 'DD/MM/YYYY') "
    wc = wc & " AND TO_DATE (" & "'" & sToDate & "'" & ", 'DD/MM/YYYY'))"
 'CASE "ATA" 
 CASE "VAD" 
    wc = wc & " AND trunc(sf_get_local(route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date,route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date_tz_code)) Between "
    wc = wc & " TO_DATE (" & "'" & sFromDate & "'" & ", 'DD/MM/YYYY') "
    wc = wc & " AND TO_DATE (" & "'" & sToDate & "'" & ", 'DD/MM/YYYY')"
 CASE "ETA"
    wc = wc & " AND TRUNC(sf_get_local(route_s.arrival_date,route_s.arrival_date_tz_code)) Between "
    wc = wc & " TO_DATE (" & "'" & sFromDate & "'" & ", 'DD/MM/YYYY') "
    wc = wc & " AND TO_DATE (" & "'" & sToDate & "'" & ", 'DD/MM/YYYY')"
END SELECT
'End If
```

I tried the below code but no luck:

```
Where (case when pstatustype='CTA' then (p_con.created_date Between     to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
                                AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))
        when pstatustype='VAD' then (route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date Between     to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
                                AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))
        when pstatustype='ETA'  then (route_s.arrival_date Between  to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') 
                                AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))
        else NULL end)
```

getting an error missing parenthesis. In then it is not taking **BETWEEN** operator.
Please help, how i can write this code in SQL developer.

Regards,
fuko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put other conditions inside the case expression clauses.

You could either switch to simpler Boolean logic:

```
Where (pstatustype='CTA' AND p_con.created_date Between to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
        AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))
   OR (pstatustype='VAD' AND route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date Between to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
        AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))
   OR (pstatustype='ETA' AND (route_s.arrival_date Between  to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
        AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))
```

or just pick the relevant date column in the case expression and compare that with a single date range:

```
Where case when pstatustype='CTA' then p_con.created_date
           when pstatustype='VAD' then route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date
           when pstatustype='ETA' then route_s.arrival_date
           else null -- default anyway
      end Between to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
              AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for your update.  I have one question : pstatustype is not a column at the DB end. this is the hard-coded value I'm using just to redirect my fromDate and Todate to different date columns. when i run this i'm getting an  error: 'Invalid Identifier as pstatustype'. how i can use this?

Comment: @fuko - where is it hard-coded? Is it supposed to be another substitution variable, that you set with a `define` (or want to be propmted for)?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for the reply. I created psstatustype as a parameter under where clause and it's working. Thank you for your help!!